# Nginx Config Issue for Ghost Blog inside a sub-directory on a LEMP Server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, node.js, ghost-blog

My Requirements

1. Ghost Blog on www.mydomain.com/blog
2. An index.html, contact.php, couple of images and js files in root directory. (i.e something like www.mydomain.com/index.html, mydomain.com/contact.php, etc)

After Reading This Tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-blog-with-ghost-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04 , I m able to run ghost on 
www.mydomain.com/blog. But Unfortunately, I Cant Access anything from root directory i.e. www.mydomain.com as it throws a 404 Error

Prior to Ghost Install Everything inside `/usr/share/nginx/www` was available on root directory. Now, I used `ls` command to check whether the files are present inside folder `/usr/share/nginx/www` and I can View these files on my terminal.

When I `cd` to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` folder, I can see 2 files **ghost** and **default** and inside `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` I can see only **ghost** file.

When I copy the **default** file from `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, Ghost Blog gives a 404 Error.

Here is The **default** file Content
        server {
                listen 80 default_server;
                listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

```
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

            # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
            server_name localhost;

            location / {
                    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                    # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                    # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
            }

            error_page 404 /404.html;
            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }

            error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
                    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            }

            location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
            }

            # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
            # concurs with nginx's one
            #
            #location ~ /\.ht {
            #       deny all;
            #}
    }
```

Here is The **ghost** file Content

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name SERVERIP/spider;
        location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
            proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found The Solution after some Intensive Google Search

Now, First I Copied The Default Ghost Config file from *sites available* folder to *sites enabled* folder using

`cp /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`

After The file Got copied,I Restarted nginx using following command 
`service nginx restart`

Now, When I refreshed The page, I couldn't see my blog but everything from the folder `/usr/share/nginx/www` being available on root directory. i.e all files from that folder were accessible on mydomain.com

Coming back to the Ghost Blog now, I made a backup of the same and removed it from the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` folder.

Instead, I pasted Following Code inside server object.

```
location ^~ /blog {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```

Restarted nginx, it worked!

Source 
https://allaboutghost.com/how-to-install-ghost-in-a-subdirectory/

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution in below url and it worked.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

  location ^~ /blog {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:2368;
      proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

https://www.ghostforbeginners.com/how-to-install-ghost-in-a-subdirectory/